# Facebook comments plugin

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the Facebook XML to load a Facebook comments plugin in my MVC 3 app, like this:

```
<fb:comments href="@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" num_posts="15" width="900"></fb:comments>
```

The problem is that the width property only renders out in pixel value. I would like to specify a percentage width instead. I examined the HTML generated when Facebook's JavaScript renders out the XML tag to full-qualified HTML. It spits out an iframe with inline css specifying the width. The iframe has a class "fb_ltr" and I tried doing a CSS rule for .fb_ltr to change the width, but because the css is inline as a `style=""` attribute this rule is overridden.

I then tried using jQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.fb_ltr').css('width', '100%');
});
```

But that didn't work either because the Facebook JavaScript takes a while to do its job and render the content. Has anyone worked with the Facebook plugins before? Customizing seems kind of convoluted. Is there a way to tie some jQuery on after the Facebook script renders out the comments iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can do it via css why not do it? just add !important and it will override everything. But I doubt that you can do it via css. Example css:

```
width: 100% !important;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about `!important` in CSS. You fixed my issue. I will accept later tonight, it is making me wait...

Answer (score 1):

try attaching a `load` event to the facebook frame:

```
$("#comments").load( function() {
    $('.fb_ltr').css('width', '100%');
});
```

Comment: I did not know I could do this either! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed this:

```
<fb:comments href="http://whatever.com" 
num_posts="10" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

to this:

```
<fb:comments href="http://whatever.com" 
num_posts="10" width="100%" style="width:100%"></fb:comments>
```

and also set the following css:

`iframe.fb_ltr {
    width:100% !important;
}`

It worked...

Comment: I tried the `width="100%"` and that did nothing, same with the `style="width: 100%;"`. It was the css rule `.fb_ltr { width: 100% !important; }` that did it. the inline attributes and styles on the FBXML element do not get rendered to the containing iFrame when javascript renders the contents. But `!important` does override the inline style that gets set on the rendered iFrame, hence the answer I accepted 2 days ago.